# Invoke and pass parameters and get the return value of certain method defined in separate jar file

Tags: java, jar, execute

Assume that I have a .jar file A which has method "long calculateSomething(String args)". A.jar is stored in folder /service. Now, I want to develop a java application which can invoke method  calculateSomething from A.jar file, execute and get the return value from this method. How can I achieve it?

Oracle has a similar example in following link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/apiindex.html

However, It call and execute the main method in A.jar file with void return. Hence, I could not apply that technique. Could you please tell me the solution for my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Remember, Java is object-oriented. Methods are in classes. Classes can be bundled together into jarfiles, but that's just a convenient way of handling them as a group. So: Which _class_ are you calling the method against?

Comment: I know exactly which class I need to call. My problem is that I want to get the return value of a certain method of 1 determined class in jar file.

Comment: Is it always the same Jar file and the same method or is this part of the user input when the application is run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your program to be able to use a class of foo.jar, foo.jar must be in the classpath, that's all.

So you'll have to compile your code with

```
javac -cp foo.jar ...
```

and to run your code with

```
java -cp foo.jar:/the/folder/where/your/classes/are ...
```

or

```
java -cp foo.jar;c:\the\folder\where\your\classes\are ...
```

if you're on Windows.

The Java code itself is exactly the same as if the class you want to use was one of your own classes, rather than a class in foo.jar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want Java code not command line

Comment: Read my answer again. "The Java code itself is exactly the same as if the class you want to use was one of your own classes". You know how to invoke a method of a class, right? Whether the class is in a jar or not is irrelevant. The code is the same. But you'll only be able to compile and run the code if the jar file containing the class is in the classpath.